# OCR tesseract gem for ruby/rails - How to install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ocr

The tesseract-ocr gem installed correctly (including dependencies). However when launching the rails server I get the following compile error. I have never received a compile error at this stage, so I would be grateful for any help.

```
server:brandlove n$ rails s
/Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4/lib/ffi/inline/compilers/gcc.rb:29:in `compile': compile error: see logs at /var/folders/hm/6n4h3d1s49b_pxt2m51gr39c0000gn/T/.ffi-inline-501/793babd774d7ac74de2eb789882efa735f45b30b.log (CompilationError)
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4/lib/ffi/inline/builders/c.rb:114:in `shared_object'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:90:in `block in build'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:87:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:87:in `build'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4/lib/ffi/inline/inline.rb:54:in `singleton_inline'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4/lib/ffi/inline/inline.rb:39:in `inline'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:34:in `<module:C>'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:31:in `<module:Tesseract>'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/api.rb:26:in `require'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/api.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract-ocr.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract-ocr.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /Users/n/Desktop/brandlove/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
server:brandlove n$
```

LOG FILE:

```
/var/folders/hm/6n4h3d1s49b_pxt2m51gr39c0000gn/T/.ffi-inline-501/793babd774d7ac74de2eb789882efa735f45b30b.cpp:1:30: error: tesseract/strngs.h: No such file or directory
/Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:51: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token
/Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:57: error: variable or field ‘destroy_string’ declared void
/Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:57: error: ‘STRING’ was not declared in this scope
/Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:57: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
/Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:63: error: ‘STRING’ was not declared in this scope
/Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:63: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
/Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:63: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
/Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:69: error: ‘STRING’ was not declared in this scope
/Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:69: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
/Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:69: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
```

Comment: Well, you actually have to look at the log file mentioned on the first line: `/var/folders/hm/6n4h3d1s49b_pxt2m51gr39c0000gn/T/.ffi-inline-501/793babd774d7ac74de2eb789882efa735f45b30b.log`

Comment: @RobertK Added log file.

Comment: Wow, kudos to the person who wrote that. It is very rare for a unix-y program to actually show you the full path to the log file, methinks.

Comment: Might help (same error as yours): https://github.com/meh/ruby-tesseract-ocr/issues/3

Comment: @JacksonHenley I had the same issue updating the `tesseract` binary helped it

Answer (score 5):

as far as i can see you use mac os...
simplest way to solve any installation mistakes is clean install :) of `tesseract` and `gem 'tesseract-ocr'`

it is pretty easy if you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh) installed

```
$ brew install tesseract
```

it will take some time and will install tesseract itself and all necessary libs

and after, of course

```
$ gem install 'tesseract-ocr'
```

(or `$ bundle install` if you added it to Gemfile)

Comment: Is there a way of doing this if you want to use `tesseract-ocr` in a gem, and not have everyone need to install it externally? In other words: Can you pack `tesseract-ocr` into a gem?

Comment: not really got your question.. `tesseract-ocr`is gem already. if you want to use it in a bundle for another gem you can define it in your new gem's Gemfile

Comment: It requires you to `brew install tesseract`, is there a way to ommit that. Say I am making a new gem: `awesome_gem`, and I want to use tesseract in this gem. However I do not want the users of the gem to have to install tesseract as well. I would like it to be simply: `gem install awesome_gem`, and they could start using it and thus tesseract. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: ammm... i guess, yes. you can include in gem anything you want like sources of tesseract and ruby-shell scripts to build it natively on each os it need to be installed to. but it would like to write mini brew inside your gem =)